# Javascript wont click on element

Tags: javascript, click

I am trying to change the value of a text area and clicking the button to submit it, but my code doesn't seem to click on the target. What could I be doing wrong? Could it be that the modal is preventing the click?

```html
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <p>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
      </p>
      <p>

      </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setValue() {

        document.getElementById('set').value = "5d10";
        document.getElementById("throw").click();
      }
    </script>

  </p>
</div>

</div>
```

**Edit:**
omg, I am SO sorry. I did not explain this well. I wrote this almost at 2 am my time. I was tired and frustrated (i spent a few hours trying to find what I was doing wrong) and did not explain myself properly. Let me try again.

What I posted was a snippet of the code where I believe is the problem since the function bit that modifies "set" does work, but the part that is supposed to click on "throw" doesn't. (ignore that empty p).

I am editing the source code of this git: https://github.com/MajorVictory/3DDiceRoller

I have managed to edit a few things like adding buttons and setting a modal from where the button you see in the snippet operates from. Visual reference: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RioM0.jpg)
[Set and Throw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ8E6.png)

In short, "document.getElementById('set').value = "5d10";" **works**, but "document.getElementById("throw").click();" **doesn't**.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, you do not have anything called `set` or `throw` either. I also suggest you use the submit event of the form instead of using script to click the button. What is the actual use case for this script?

Comment: You cannot nest P elements

Answer (score 0):

There is no element called 'set' in your html code.
The correct code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Training File Upload</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p></p>
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
        <input type="button" id='set' value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
      </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function setValue() {

          document.getElementById('set').value = "5d10";
        }
      </script>

    </p>
  </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: of course the code is working; I just ran the snippet.

Comment: You are mistaken, my code and answer are absolutely correct. If I am mistaken, then you can suggest an edit.

Comment: Now you removed the `throw` the code no longer gives error but is this now what OP asked?

Comment: I'm sorry but I had actually added the throw element. It seems that it somehow got deleted from the code. I am rather not comfortable with SO's editor. There has been a misunderstanding,

Comment: corrected. But it does not matter much, browsers automatically close <p> elements if not closed.

Comment: I have expanded my question with more information. I apologize for not being more clear.